# Pass Dynamic List of Parameters and Values to a C# Method to execute SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, .net, ssis

I have a method in C# to execute a stored procedure.  This will be called from a Script Component in SSIS 2014 (which also calls out to a web service for data).  I'd like to be able to pass a dynamic list of SQL Parameters and Values.  I was thinking about just using an array (`string [,]`), but in reality I think it's more of a key-value pair since I really only need 2 columns.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Here's what I have so far (semi-working .NET Fiddle example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dALwJ0)):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        // Code for getting data from web service goes here.

        string[,] paramsArray = new string[,]
        {
            {"@ShipmentId", "123456"},
            {"@TransDate", "2016-01-25"},
            {"@FromLocation", "123"},
            {"@ToLocation", "456"},
            {"@Status", "Delivered"},
            {"@TrackingNo", "1Z456789123"},
            {"@UpdatedAtCarrier", DateTime.Now.ToString()},
        };

        SqlStoredProcedureParamArrayNoReturn("My Connection String", "My_Stored_Proc_To_Run", paramsArray);
    }


    public static void SqlStoredProcedureParamArrayNoReturn(string dbConnection, string procName, string[,] paramArray)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < paramArray.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(paramArray[r,0] + " =>  " + paramArray[r,1]);
        }
        if (paramArray.GetLength(1) != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("paramArray has too few/too many columns. Exiting method...");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("paramArray has too few/too many columns. Exiting method...");
        }

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procName, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            for (int r = 0; r < paramArray.GetLength(0); r++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(paramArray[r, 0], paramArray[r, 1]));
            }
            cmd.Connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SQL Command executed successfully.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on this code, you know there's absolutely no reason to have written a Script Task for this, right? Add an Execute SQL Task. Your input will become `EXEC dbo.My_Stored_Proc_To_Run ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?` (assuming I counted seven) for an OLE DB connection manager and for an ADO.NET it will be with named parameters, thus `@ShipmentId, @TransDate,..`

Comment: @billinkc - Updated the question to provide a little more clarity since I was initially trying to keep the code concise.  The Script Component is also grabbing data from a web service, but otherwise if it wasn't then, yes, an Execute SQL Task would be one way to handle it.